# OAuth2 Provider Architecture - Should requests w/ Access_Tokens be accompanied by Client_Key & Client_Secret as well?

Tags: node.js, sdk, oauth-2.0

I'm building an OAuth2 Provider and API on Node.js.

I've built the system to grant `access_tokens` and require `client_key` and `client_secret` to do so...

But once an `access_token` has been granted, and a Client User performs a GET or POST request to an API resource, is it common to pass the `client_key` and `client_secret` along with that request, and all subsequent requests?

I've always been under the impression that only an `access_token` was needed, but after reviewing some SDKs (like this [Twitter node API client](https://github.com/reneraab/node-twitter-api/blob/master/twitter.js)), they are using OAuth Clients to perform subsequent requests to API resources, and it looks like the `client_secret` and `client_key` are being included each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification requires the access token only. The authorization server itself is definitely able to look up every authorization detail for token.

However, in some use cases the protected resource should also be able to identify the client (e.g. do access logging), but the specification does not cover how this should be done. Using JWS or other self-contained tokens you can extract the client id (and everything else) from the token manually, but the server is free to use different token representations as well.

As a conclusion, including client info besides the access token is probably a custom implementation detail of Twitter and others for protected resources to identify their client.