# As an Oauth2 service provider, how do I validate which app is passing me the user token?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have a pretty good handle on Oauth2 having connected to several services as a client. Now, I'm working on implementing a service that clients will connect to with Oauth2.

It seems wrong to just accept any valid user access token without validating that the app that is giving it to me is in fact the app that I first gave the token to. In the Oauth2 spec, and in several articles including [this one](http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified), the topic isn't discussed. Is there a standard way for the client to tell me who they are, in addition to the user token they are giving me?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way for client identification, this is intentionally missing from the spec.

If you are free to make your own choices in your implementation, the closest thing would be using JWS tokens. They contain authorization data in JSON format and are signed, but not encrypted. A protected resource itself can easily validate JWS tokens without consulting the authorization server and can trivially extract any authorization detail as desired, e.g. the client id.

Another possibility may be to explicitly add a client_id to the request (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966935/oauth2-provider-architecture-should-requests-w-access-tokens-be-accompanied-b/)), but that is far from being standard.